# How to migrate iOS project from 2.0 to 2.8 Vuforia SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vuforia

As you all know that we can migrate project from 2.8 to 3.0 from this link [Migration Link](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/migrating-your-ios-sdk-project), but my project is using 2.0 so I want to know that how can I migrate my project from 2.0 to 2.8 then I can jump into 2.8 to 3.0, becuase I just noted that my project's integrate QCAR has "UIGLViewProtocol.h" and "QCAR_iOS.h" so there is no help I found in 2.8 to 3.0 link for alternate of these classes.
Kindly help me on this how to migrate my project correctly on 3.0.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: What is broad in question, I just need to migrate 2.0 to 2.8 and there is no link I found for this, so looking for that link?

Comment: Then that makes your question off topic as well as too broad.

Comment: So there will no solution for this?

Comment: Not on this site. Attempt the migration and come back with specific questions.

Comment: Already attempted so thats why putting question on these two files "UIGLViewProtocol.h" and "QCAR_iOS.h", these files exist in last QCAR folder and not in 3.0 folder and there is no help regarding these files in 2.8 to 3.0 migration and getting not found "UIGLViewProtocol.h" and "QCAR_iOS.h"